# typescript - typed functions can be called with parameter of any type?

Tags: typescript

I'm using TS 0.9.5 and something just hit me.

`class X { }`

`class Y { }`

`function y(p: Y) { }`

`y(new X);`

How can this compile without errors? We have implicit any disabled, so it should be strongly typed. Is this a bug?

Here a playground sample: http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=class%20X%20%7B%20%7D%0A%0Aclass%20Y%20%7B%0A%7D%0A%0Afunction%20y(p%3A%20Y)%20%7B%20%7D%0Ay(new%20X)%3B

**edit:** Now I understand the thing about empty classes. The thing is I had a different issue and tried to simplify. I simplified too much.

I actually have that problem with multiple overloads and one implementation with less specific signature.

Here the one that does compile but should not:
[sample 1](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=class%20AsyncQueryable%3CT%3E%20%7B%0A%09%20public%20take%28count%3a%20number%29%3a%20AsyncQueryable%3CT%3E%20%7B%0A%09%09return%20this;%09%20%0A%09%20%7D%0A%09%20%0A%09%20public%20skip%28count%3a%20number%29%3a%20AsyncQueryable%3CT%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this;%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0A%0A%0Amodule%20m%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20export%20interface%20IFilters%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5Bkey%3a%20string%5D%3a%20string%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%09%0A%09export%20interface%20IListViewSource%3CT%3E%20%7B%7D%0A%09%0A%0A%20%20%20%20export%20function%20queryViewSource%3CT%3E%28source%3a%20%28filters%3a%20IFilters%29%20=%3E%20AsyncQueryable%3CT%3E,%20added?%3a%20T%29%3a%20IListViewSource%3CT%3E%0A%20%20%20%20export%20function%20queryViewSource%3CT%3E%28source%3a%20AsyncQueryable%3CT%3E,%20added?%3a%20T%29%3a%20IListViewSource%3CT%3E%0A%20%20%20%20export%20function%20queryViewSource%3CT%3E%28sourceAny%3a%20any,%20added?%3a%20T%29%3a%20IListViewSource%3CT%3E%20%7B%0A%09%09return%20null;%0A%09%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Am.queryViewSource%28%5B%5D%29;%0A%0A)

and heres the version that won't compile like expected but the implementations parameters and return types are completely unspecific: [sample 2](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=class%20AsyncQueryable%3CT%3E%20%7B%0A%09%20public%20take%28count%3a%20number%29%3a%20AsyncQueryable%3CT%3E%20%7B%0A%09%09return%20this;%09%20%0A%09%20%7D%0A%09%20%0A%09%20public%20skip%28count%3a%20number%29%3a%20AsyncQueryable%3CT%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this;%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0A%0A%0Amodule%20m%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20export%20interface%20IFilters%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5Bkey%3a%20string%5D%3a%20string%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%09%0A%09export%20interface%20IListViewSource%3CT%3E%20%7B%7D%0A%09%0A%0A%20%20%20%20export%20function%20queryViewSource%3CT%3E%28source%3a%20%28filters%3a%20IFilters%29%20=%3E%20AsyncQueryable%3CT%3E,%20added?%3a%20T%29%3a%20IListViewSource%3CT%3E%0A%20%20%20%20export%20function%20queryViewSource%3CT%3E%28source%3a%20AsyncQueryable%3CT%3E,%20added?%3a%20T%29%3a%20IListViewSource%3CT%3E%0A%20%20%20%20export%20function%20queryViewSource%3CT%3E%28sourceAny%3a%20any,%20added?%3a%20any%29%3a%20any%20%7B%0A%09%09return%20null;%0A%09%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Am.queryViewSource%28%5B%5D%29;%0A%0A)

I'm sorry it's a little convoluted sample.

Comment: It's less clear what your question is now. Why do you think the first one shouldn't compile?

Comment: The first sample shouldn't compile because of the specs: http://www.typescriptlang.org/Content/TypeScript%20Language%20Specification.pdf
page 77 / 78 "Note that the signature of the actual function implementation is not included in the type."

Comment: Yes, sorry for that. The problem with the first one is that the implementation of the queryViewSource should be invisible and not callable. it's not in the list of overloads, but yet it's compiles fine.

Comment: @sharpjohnny Way to change your question, I hope that's your upvote against my answer, now that you understand empty classes. :) I have looked at Sample 1, but I am not seeing what you are seeing. You are exporting `queryViewSource` why should it be invisible?

Comment: yes thats my upvote, thanks :P the implementation must be exported, it wouldn't build otherwise. if you type in `m.queryViewSource(` you should see the dropdown-list of available overloads, eg. the two signatures, but the implementation itself is not available. But still you can pass in `any` parameter even if it's not visible as a overload.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a bug. TypeScript will ignore empty classes, interfaces and modules. As such because both X and Y are empty the type checking does not apply.

For the strong type checking of Y to work, you must define a property in Y.

```
class X {
}

class Y {
    name : string;
}

function y(p: Y) { }

y(new X()); // Fails because Y is now defined, and X is not compatible.
```

It is by design.

Comment: (Unfortunately, the question seems to have changed quite a lot, making your answer less relevant. You might want to have a look at the updated question. :)  ).